# Is it possible to implement foldl/foldr using unsided fold?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, mapreduce, racket, lambda-calculus

By unsided fold, I mean a hypothetic primitive fold operation for associative operators that, does not guarantee any ordering. That is, `(fold + 0 [a b c d])` could be `(+ (+ a b) (+ c d))` or `(+ (+ (+ a b) c) d)`.

Given that this operation is fusionable, highly paralelizable and universal, I've thought in including it together with `map` and `concat` as the only list primitives for my non-recursive minimalist language. I've managed to implement most list functions with it, but not the sided folds `foldl`/`foldr`themselves. Is it possible?

Comment: How about [hoogling for `fold`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fold)?

Comment: to paraphrase the Haskell answer you got, in Haskell this sequential rearranging is done by delaying, folding the functional composition over (with its inherent application order), and final application of the zero element. This translates `a + b` to `(a+) . (b+)` for `foldr`, or to `(a+) >>> (b+)` for `foldl` ( *`(f.g) x = f (g x)` ; `(f>>>g) x = g (f x)`*). Your language should support partial application, then. Evaluation forces rearrangement. Or, you could reify this as explicit degenerate trees, `[a [b [c [d]]]]` or `[[[[a] b] c] d]`, if you allow heterogenous arrays.

Comment: @WillNess uh huh, interesting! Interestingly, some of my compile targets do not support high order functions (such as C). So, in a way, `fold` is not enough to make my language complete. I've had to give up of it in favor of `foldl` as one of the few primitives. So I now need guarantees of associativity to make it parallel. I'm learning a lot and having much fun, though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `fold` and `map` that is universal.  The slogan here is [foldr is made of monoids](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/) In fact, the standard haskell typeclass `Foldable` implements `foldr` and `foldl` [in just this way](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v%3afoldMap)

The trick is that the set of endomorphisms over a set forms a monoid under function composition with the identity function as the identity.

Note though that `foldr` and `foldl` are inherently sequential.  So, this trick has to give up any parallelism you have in your implementation of `fold` and `map`.  Essentially, the encoding of `foldr` into `foldMap` is the encoding of a delayed sequential computation into a potentially unordered one.  That is why I encourage the use of `foldMap` over `foldr` when possible--it supports implicit parallism when that is possible, but is equivalent in expressive power.

EDIT: Putting everything in one place

We define the set of endo morphisms over `a`

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
    mempty = Endo id
    Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```

then in foldable, we see the definition for `foldr`

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
```

this uses `foldMap` which has type `Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m` (where `t` is the collection we are folding over, we can pretend it is a list from now on giving `Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m` and is equivalent to

```
foldMap f ls = fold (map f ls)
```

where `fold` is the monoid fold.  If you have a unordered fold called `fold' :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> [a] -> a` then that is just

```
fold = fold' mappend mempty
```

so

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
 = appEndo (fold (map (Endo . f) t)) z
 = appEndo (fold' mappend mempty (map (Endo . f) t)) z
 = appEndo (fold' (\(Endo f) (Endo g) -> Endo (f . g) (Endo id) (map (Endo . f) t)) z
```

which can be further simplified to

```
foldr f z t = (fold' (.) id (map f t)) z
```

and dropping the unecessary parens

```
foldr f z t = fold' (.) id (map f t) z
```

which is what Daniel Wagner gave as his answer.  You can implement `foldl` in a similar way, or via `foldr`.

Comment: Hmm pardon I like your answer and it seems like you really know what you are talking about, but how exactly can I implement foldr with fold and map alone? I know pretty much anything about monoids - please visualize this toy language that is pretty much lambda calculus + numbers + arrays with those 3 operations and no recursion. Can this be done?

Comment: Just an example to illustrate: `map = (λ(λ(mapreduce (λ(list ((2 0)))) conc nil 0))); zipWith = (λ(λ(λ(map(λ(3(get 0 3) (get 0 1))) (range 0 (len 1))))))`. Those numbers are bruijn indexes for variables, don't mind them. I've implemented many functions similarly, using just `mapreduce`, `list`, `conc`, `nil`. But foldl... I'm clueless. I don't know how to simulate the sequencing aspect, considering `mapreduce` (the unsided fold) doesn't guarantee a order of operation. How?

Comment: @Viclib As mentioned in the answer, just look at the source for `Foldable` to see the default implementations of `foldr` and `foldl` in terms of `foldMap`.

Comment: OK, all I know is this worked! I've spent the last hour since you posted trying to figure out everything that is going on, but there are too many concepts I don't know yet. Well, I'll be studying that answer for a long time today, but this really helped me. Thank you very much, wish I could you tick you twice.

Comment: "Note though that `foldr` and `foldl` are inherently sequential. So, this trick has to give up any parallelism you have in your implementation of `fold` and `map`." Now, let's be careful with this statement, and distinguish between the specific `foldr`/`fold` implementations, and folds in general. Many left and right folds can be parallelized by using a parallel prefix scan algorithm; read in that light, your statement here is false. The `fold`/`Endo` implementation of `foldr`/`fold`, however, won't parallelize; read that way, your statement is true.

Comment: @LuisCasillas the **type** of `foldr` is inherently sequential.  It produces a sequential data dependency--the point is that `foldr` can't assume its argument is associative, and in fact it can't be associative because the type of the two arguments are different.  The parallel prefix scan requires a semigroup.  The point of my statement is that `fold` with an associative operation is different than `foldl`/`foldr` which are inherently sequential.

Answer (score 3):

```
foldr f z xs = fold (.) id (map f xs) z
```

For example, in ghci:

```
*Dmwit Debug.SimpleReflect> let foldr' f z xs = foldb (.) id (map f xs) z
*Dmwit Debug.SimpleReflect> foldr' f z [w,x,y]
f w (f x (f y z))
*Dmwit Debug.SimpleReflect> foldr f z [w,x,y]
f w (f x (f y z))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm ticking Philip as he explained it to details after you posted, but this helped a lot.